# Opening a json file with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, button

I am trying to open a json file in javascript,

```js
function test() {
  
    const jsonData= require('logins.json'); 

    alert(jsonData)
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>test</title>
  <script defer src="test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  
</body>
    <button onclick="test()">test</button>
</html>
```

this is not working and logins.json is a thing, this is what is in it:

```
{

"Students":[
    {
        "username":"test",
        "password":"testi"    }
  ]
 }
```

any help is great, do I need to use Ajax or is it a silly mistake? I am new to javascript.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Help others reproduce the problem". When I click on the button, I get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined". There are hundreds of questions about this error on Stack Overflow already.

Answer (score 2):

Node.js provides a `require` function which can load JSON.

You are running your JavaScript embedded in a `<script>` element in a web page in a browser, not Node.

> do I need to use Ajax

Yes.

Give the JSON file a URL, use the `fetch` API to request it.